# Removing duplicates in two vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, duplicates, std-pair

> I'll try to explain my problem with the following example:

```
vector<pair<string, string>> a = { { "A","1" }, {"B","2" },{ "C","3" },{ "D","3" },{ "E","5" } };

vector<pair<string, string>> b = { { "A","1" },{ "B","3" },{ "D","3" },{ "E","4" },{ "Z","5" } };
```

What will be the most efficient way to erase duplicates and get the output into the same vectors? The number of pairs is pretty large, lets say about 100 000.

**Both vectors are sorted by the first element.**

```
vector<pair<string, string>> a = { { "B","2" },{ "C","3" },{ "E","5" } };

vector<pair<string, string>> b = { { "B","3" },{ "E","4" },{ "Z","5" } };
```

The thing is, I need to compare this vectors after removing duplicates.
First element in the pair is the file path, and second is the checksum for it.
So for example if i have `"B","2"` in the first container, and `"B","3"` is the second, i can list this file as "modified". I am open to use `std::set` if this would make this problem easier.

Comment: When you say duplicates, do you mean pairs that exist identically in both containers? Do you need [one of the standard algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)?

Comment: "efficient" in terms of speed, memory, coding time?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes, i mean pairs that exist identically in both containers, but I'd rather do not create a new vector. I will need these two vectors to compare them further.
Efficient - speed and memory

Comment: if you're looking for sorted and unique elements in container then why not Set ?  It's easy to convert vector to set in C++11 style:                            
    std::set<pair<string,string>>  
    s(std::make_move_iterator(a.begin()),      
                                                     std::make_move_iterator(a.end()));

Comment: Getting something that's optimal in time _and_ optimal in space is generally difficult. Algorithms are about making trade-offs, usually between those two things. I believe the standard algorithms for this operation require a distinct target container; you may be able to come up with something that works in-place, but it'll almost certainly be slower.

Comment: @ArchieYalakki: That is not the same thing. OP misused the term "duplicates" and is looking to produce the "difference" of two containers. There's no indication that the individual input containers should not themselves contain duplicates.

Comment: Choose time or space. if you allocate new vectors, a solution in `O(max(len(a), len(b))` is trivial. If not it's harder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using running indices will give you O(len(a) + len(b)) time complexity and O(1) additional space (Given `a` and `b` are already sorted)

```
void removeDuplicate(vector<pair<string, string>>& a, vector<pair<string, string>>& b) {

    //Add these two lines if there can be duplicates in a or b themselves.
    //a.erase(std::unique(a.begin(), a.end()), a.end());
    //b.erase(std::unique(b.begin(), b.end()), b.end());

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;

    size_t p1 = 0;
    size_t p2 = 0;

    while(i < a.size() && j < b.size()) {
        if(a[i] == b[j]) {
            i++;
            j++;
        } else if (a[i] > b[j]) {
            b[p2++] = b[j++]; 
        } else if (b[j] > a[i]) {
            a[p1++] = a[i++];
        }
    }

    while(i < a.size()) {
        a[p1++] = a[i++]; 
    }

    while(j < b.size()) {
        b[p2++] = b[j++];
    }

    a.erase(a.begin()+p1, a.end());
    b.erase(b.begin()+p2, b.end());
}
```

Comment: Might use `if (p1 != i) a[p1] = std::move(a[i]); ++p1; ++i;` to avoid string copies. And then it might or might not be worth trying to do an initial skip before the main loop so you don't need those `if` branches.

Comment: Any particular reason for using indexes over iterators?

Comment: @aschepler That's true! I almost forgot that. move would be much more efficient than copying in this case!

Comment: @Caleth No particular reasons :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think any of the standard library algorithms will be directly helpful here.

We first check to see if we should remove (from both), otherwise we advance the iterator pointing to the lesser value and continue.

```
for (auto ait = a.begin(), bit = b.begin(); ait != a.end() && bit != b.end();)
{
    if (*ait == *bit)
    {
        // Potenitally multiple duplicate values
        ait = a.erase(std::remove(ait, a.end(), *ait), a.end());
        bit = b.erase(std::remove(bit, b.end(), *bit), b.end());
    }
    else if (*ait < *bit) ++ait;
    else ++bit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some algorithms from STL library to help solve this task. Firstly find same elements and put them in temporary vector, then remove these elements from each vector, see code example:

```
vector<pair<string, string>> a = { { "A","1" }, {"B","2" },{ "C","3" },{ "D","3" },{ "E","5" } };
vector<pair<string, string>> b = { { "A","1" },{ "B","3" },{ "D","3" },{ "E","4" },{ "Z","5" } };

//Vector to hold same elements
vector<pair<string, string>> same_elements {};

//Fill same_elements vector
std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [&same_elements, b]( pair<string, string>& el )
              {
                  if( find(b.begin(), b.end(), el) != b.end() )
                  {
                      same_elements.push_back(el);
                  }
              });

//Remove same elements from a and b
std::for_each(same_elements.begin(), same_elements.end(), [&a, &b]( pair<string, string>& el_to_delete )
              {
                  auto It_a = find(a.begin(), a.end(), el_to_delete);
                  if( It_a != a.end() )
                  {
                      a.erase(It_a);
                  }

                  auto It_b = find(b.begin(), b.end(), el_to_delete);
                  if( It_b != b.end() )
                  {
                      b.erase(It_b);
                  }
              });
```

I used `std::for_each` to iterate over every elements of vector, `std::find` to find needed elements in vectors and `erase` vector method to erase same element from vector by iterator.

Comment: you create a new vector and you don't use the fact that `a` and `b` are sorted (you could use `std::binary_search` for instance, or play with `std::set_intersection`).

Comment: @papagaga Actually when I started writing answer there was no word about sorted vectors, OP added it later